# Android Override multitasking-key

Tags: android, galaxy

I have an older Android App with the old legacy menu button and do not plan to update this at the moment. On newer hardware - Samsung Galaxy S5 - the menu button is removed and replaced with a "Multitasking"-button. I know a longpress will show the menu - However, is there a way to override the new "Multitasking"-button on the the same way as one can do

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, is there a way to override the new "Multitasking"-button on the the same way as one can do

Not at the level of an SDK app. A ROM mod or other firmware build could do what it wants with that key.